# Regular Expression to match only numbers, (, ), + and -

Tags: regex

What is the correct regular expression to match only number, parentheses, plus and minus signs?

I've spent a long time on http://rubular.com/ and I came up with this for matching numbers only:

```
/\A[^a-zA-Z]*\z/
```

How can I do this so that it also matches for parentheses, plus and minus signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[\d()+-]+$/
```

Comment: @hszeto - Heads up, if you ever need to include a dash in a character class **always** specify it last.  For example, the character class `[+-_]` matches `+`, `_`, *and everything in between*.  If you cannot specify it last, be sure to escape it.